# Updating shapefile from ArcMap to ArcGIS Online - Automatically

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-online, arcgis-10.5, arcgis-online-webmap

I wish to update a Cities shapefile* in desktop ArcMap (10.5.1), and I would want this layer to be automatically updated (synced?) to a Cities layer in my US Severe Weather Alerts map on ArcGIS Online.

Is there a way to complete this process in the fewest steps? I'm already aware of the manual append upload method, but there has to be a more automatic way. How can I do this?

- I know there are plenty of cities GIS layers, but the one I'm updating includes small unincorporated communities in addition to the cities that are typically available.

Comment: Are you planning to update existing cities attributes or just add new cities now and then? Where are you getting the new attributes/the new cities from?

Comment: ESRI publishes this tutorial for uploading spatial data to AGOL.  You could create the script and run it as a scheduled task in Windows.  I am unclear whether this will overwrite and existing file or not. https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/python/import-data/

Comment: @MarceloVilla, I'm adding additional towns with possible updates to some of the original attributes (original layer provided cities > 10,000 population). If I update the original attributes, I would only update the point location (and maybe the name if there's an incorrect spelling. For new points, I use the topographic basemap and place points on where the communities are.

Comment: @GBG I'm not very good at using Python, but that does seem like a step in the right direction for what I'm looking for. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: [non python route] we use FME Server to upload to AGOL nightly not sure if that is an option for you.

Comment: @Mapperz   Thanks for that idea!